# Pantech USB UML290 AT+CNMI not working

Tags: at-command, modem

I'm trying to get SMS notifications to be sent to my terminal (putty/Hyperterm/etc.) over the AT COM port for a Pantech USB UML290 (Verizon) modem. I can send and receive SMS's just fine using text mode with `AT+CMGS` and `AT+CMGL="ALL"` so the modem is working. I just can't get notifications via `CNMI`:

I've set up text mode using:

```
AT+CMGF=1
OK

AT+CMGF?

+CMGF: 1
OK
```

And I've setup `CNMI` as `2,2,0,0,0`:

```
AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0

OK

AT+CNMI=2

OK

AT+CNMI?

+CNMI: 2,2,0,0,0
OK
```

I never receive a `+CMT` or `+CMTI` on putty

Is the Pantech UML290 not capable of notifying the terminal/TE on SMS received? `AT+CLAC` shows `AT+CNMI` as a valid command. Am I missing something?